# Django & Celery unexpected behavior when saving to JSONField

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

Have celery task started using celery beat with code something like this:

```py
class Data(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(null=True)

    def store_data(self):
        data = []
        
        data.append(1)
        data.append(2)

        self.data = data
        self.save()

        data.append(3)
        return data
```

I would expected that stored data would be [1, 2] but the reality is [1, 2, 3]. I was trying to find out if celery using atomic or something like this that would explain it but no success. Is this expected behavior? Works fine outside celery.

Fix is to use deepcopy like this:

```py
...
data_to_save = copy.deepcopy(data)
self.data = data_to_save
self.save()
...
```

but I would like to know why it doesn't work without it

Comment: please share the scheduler function

Comment: use print statement after every instruction, you'll be able to track the order of execution. also add before_save and after_save signals to track saving in database